# Troubleshooting NTP mystery, any ideas?

Tags: ntp

Task:  NTP to a local Synology box (NTP is turned on on the box).

Observations (AV and firewall turned off for testing):

My C# code (unchanged from when it used to work):  Timeout on the receive stage.  (Note that the code is running correctly on the production server, this failure is only in my environment.)

Windows 7 itself, "An error occurred while Windows was synchronizing with 192.168.1.202."  (Edit:  Now it's decided to listen.  Nothing's changed.)

However, w32tm /stripchart /computer:192.168.1.202 is able to get the time!

Trying both commands with time.windows.com works.

How can it both be working (according to w32tm) and not working (according to the time updater)?  My server name is not Heisenberg!

Comment: Perhaps Windows 7 sends extra packets or something of the like to time.windows.com and it authenticates it (somehow), althought if w32tm works then I doubt it. Perhaps run a Wireshark analysis on both w32tm and the windows 7 time utility to see if theres any differences in the packets.

Comment: Also to add, perhaps there's extra information being passed to Windows time utility as opposed to w32tm, and your Synology box can't service the Windows' bizarre time requests and it fails to fully send the time? Could there also be some sort of whitelist to only service certain program requests and not other programs?

Comment: @QuickishFM Good point about Wireshark, I didn't think of it.  However, my code only sends the one packet, if it were extra packets from the time utility mine should still work.

Comment: @QuickishFM No whitelist on the Synology--when I wrote it I simply turned on the time service and everything worked.

Comment: ah, right then. Everything on the synology end is probably good then

Comment: "Perhaps there's extra information being passed to Windows time utility" - This is not the case.  `w32tm` and the associated service uses standard NTP packets.

Comment: @QuickishFM While I haven't solved it Wireshark sure helped pin it down--it **is** working, I'm just not getting the packet for some reason.  I'm too much of a software guy, I didn't think of looking at the wire.  Thanks!